# Position label widget inside frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

As mentioned in the topic title, I am trying to position a label widget inside a frame using grid() method and its coordinate arguments "row"/"column". Tweaking these arguments simply does not work in that my label widget stays at the topleft of the frame. I would like to position the label at my convenience inside **master_frame** using only grid().

Code :

```
import tkinter as tk

class myForm:
    def __init__(self, master_window):

      master_window.geometry('800x800')
      master_window.title("My App")

      master_frame = tk.Frame(master=master_window, bg="blue")
      master_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.W, tk.E))
      master_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
      master_window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

      MetadataTitle = tk.Label(master=master_frame, text="1) Enter metadata :", font(None, 16))
      MetadataTitle.grid(row=3, column=3) # test coordinates
 
 
##
root = tk.Tk()
myform = myForm(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIZ49.png)

I'm totally new with tkinter and I probably don't fully understand all of its concepts. Didn't find equivalent topic.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Where do you expect it to be placed? Empty rows and columns do not take up space by default.

Comment: Since there is no other widget in rows and columns before the label, the size of those rows and columns are all zero.  Therefore the label is always put at the top-left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Set the size of empty rows and columns in the grid

You can place a widget inside a frame using just `grid()`.

```py
import tkinter as tk


class myForm:
    def __init__(self, master_window):

        master_window.geometry('600x600')
        master_window.title("My App")
        master_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        master_window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        master_frame = tk.Frame(master=master_window, bg="blue")
        master_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.W, tk.E))

        # set the number of rows and columns
        # minimum size, in screen units (px)
        master_frame.columnconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), weight=1, minsize=30)  # choose appropriate size
        master_frame.rowconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), weight=1, minsize=30)  # here minsize is optional

        # another option is to add blank labels to the row and set their width (in characters)
        # you can fill in all empty cells
        
        # row 3
        label_3_3 = tk.Label(master_frame, text="1) Enter metadata :", font=(None, 16))
        label_3_3.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

        
        entry_3_4 = tk.Entry(master_frame)
        entry_3_4.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)


root = tk.Tk()
myform = myForm(root)

root.update_idletasks()

# if the content of the window is greater than root.geometry()
root.minsize(width=root.winfo_reqwidth(), height=root.winfo_reqheight())

# check width and height
print(root.winfo_geometry())
print(root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height())
print(root.winfo_reqwidth(), root.winfo_reqheight())
print(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight())

root.mainloop()
```

[grid manual page](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/grid.htm)

---

[image: Set the size of empty rows and columns in the grid tkinter example]